# How to calculate MAX/MIN of division of two function on the fly, without actually printing table on the screen?

Tags: function, division

I am trying to calculate the min/max value of the table below, however I want to do it on the fly without actually printing the table on the screen.

**Table:**

[image]

Regards,
Neeraj

Comment: Excel has a min and max function you could use.

Comment: i don't want to use table....using query just want min/ max directly in cell in google sheet

Comment: query(A1:E,"Select Max(E), Min(E)",1) something like this?

Comment: I don't want the table on my google sheet (shown in the yellow box in image). That table we print using google finance function than calculate DSMA (shown in the image how to calculate it) then calculate SRT values (see image how to calculate) than run min/max command....but here I just want min/max SRT value using some function or code so that only min/max SRT is I get.  hope I am clear to you.